# Integrating $e^{-x^2}x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, laplace-transform

> Show that $\mathcal{L}\{t^{1/2}\}=\sqrt{\pi}/(2s^{3/2}), \: s>0$

By the definition of Laplace transform we get:

$$\mathcal{L}\{t^{1/2}\} = \int_0^\infty t^{1/2}e^{-st} \, dt = \{x = \sqrt{st} \} = \dfrac{2}{s^{3/2}} \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} x^2 \, dx. $$

A known and easily proved result is $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \, dx = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$. How (if possible) can I use this result to determine the integral above? I was thinking either integration by parts or perhaps a suitable coordinate transformation (e.g. polar coordinates) but my attempts failed.

Comment: Use Feynman's trick.  Change variables by $dx=tu^2du$, and differentiate with respect to $t$ and substitute $t=1$.

Comment: @kimchi lover  Are you perhaps a fan of "The Big Bang Theory?" I had never heard of Feynman's trick until an episode in which Sheldon is trying to prove Wollowitz is not smart enough to take Sheldon's graduate physics course. Sheldon asks Wollowitz how he would evaluate a certain integral, which might be the one in question, and Wollowitz responds "Use Feynman's trick."

Comment: Sorry: I'm not, particularly.  The trick really works, though, and is well worth knowing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite the integral as $$\int\limits_0^\infty-\frac{x}{2} \left(-2xe^{-x^2}\right)dx$$ and use integration by parts with $f(x) = -\frac{x}{2}$ and $g(x) = e^{-x^2}$ to obtain $$\left. -\frac x 2 e^{-x^2}\right|_0^\infty + \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-x^2} \, dx = \int_0^\infty \frac x 2 e^{-x^2} \Big( 2x\, dx \Big) = \int_0^\infty \frac {\sqrt u} 2  e^{-u} \, du = \frac 1 2 \Gamma\left( \frac 3 2 \right).
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider integration by parts on

$$
\left(
x\,e^{-x^2}
\right)
\cdot x
$$

Answer (score 0):

Start off with the substitution $u=x^2$ such that$$I=\frac 12\int\limits_0^{\infty}du\,\sqrt ue^{-u}$$The latter integral is just simply the factorial function.$$n!=\int\limits_0^{\infty}dt\,t^ne^{-t}$$So$$I=\frac 12\left(\frac 12\right)!=\frac {\sqrt{\pi}}4$$

Answer (score 0):

You can try integration by parts with  $u=x$ and $dv=xe^{-x^2}dx$ to evaluate$$  \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} x^2 \, dx.$$ Note that,$du=dx$ and $v=-(1/2)e^{-x^2}.$ Therefore; $$\int e^{-x^2} x^2 \, dx=-(1/2)xe^{-x^2} +1/2\int e^{-x^2}\,dx.$$ Upon evaluating from $0$ to $\infty$,the first term vanishes and you get $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} x^2 \, dx=1/2\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}4.$$